# Kivy screen isn't able to call function in py

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having trouble calling a function in the .kv file. I get " AttributeError: 'ScreenManager' object has no attribute 'text_wait'" with app.root, and "AttributeError: 'FirstScreen' object has no attribute 'text_wait'" with just root. I'm assuming it's something to do with the multiple wnidows that im using, but is there a way to fix this?

kv code:

```
<FirstScreen>:
    canvas:
    
        Color:
            rgb: (255/255, 170/255, 235/255)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    Button:
        id: obama_text
        size_hint: (.274, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x":.067, "y":.049}
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, .5, .6, .85
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1
        text: "OBAMA"
        on_release: app.root.text_wait("burger") #      gives an error
<SecondScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Go to third"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint: .2, .2
            on_release: root.manager.current = "third"
<ThirdScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "go to fourth"
            size_hint: .3, .1
            pos_hint: {"x": .3, "y": .5}
            on_release: root.manager.current = "fourth"

<FourthScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "go to first"
            size_hint: .3, .1
            pos_hint: {"x": .3, "y": .5}
            on_release: root.manager.current = "first"
```

.py code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
import time
Window.fullscreen = True

Builder.load_file("test.kv")

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    pass

class FourthScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name="first"))
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name="second"))
        sm.add_widget(ThirdScreen(name="third"))
        sm.add_widget(FourthScreen(name="fourth"))
        return sm

    def text_wait(self, text):
        #for i in text:
            #print(i)
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text_wait` method is an instance method of the MyApp class. So you simply need to call `app.text_wait`.  You just need to remove the `root` part of the directive in your .kv file.

```
<FirstScreen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (255/255, 170/255, 235/255)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    Button:
        id: obama_text
        size_hint: (.274, .2)
        pos_hint: {"x":.067, "y":.049}
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, .5, .6, .85
        font_size: 50
        bold: True
        color: 200/255, 0/255, 70/255, 1
        text: "OBAMA"
        on_release: app.text_wait("burger") #      gives an error
...
```